# What spot does Shiva consider most sacred?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva

What spot does Shiva consider most sacred? A temple, mount Kailasha, swarga, etc?

Does any scripture talk about Shiva's most sacred spot according to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What spot does Shiva consider most sacred?

**The crematorium.**

According to the [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b106.htm), Shiva considers the crematorium/cemetery (smashana) the most sacred.

> "Uma said, 'Thou hast many abodes in heaven, of diverse forms and possessed of every comfort and luxury. Why, O holy one, dost thou reside in the crematorium, abandoning all those delightful mansions? The crematorium is full of the hair and bones (of the dead), abounds with vulture and jackals, and is strewn with hundreds of funeral pyres. Full of carrion and muddy with fat and blood, with entrails and bones strewn all over it, and always echoing with the howls of jackals, it is certainly an unclean place.'
>
> "Maheswara said, 'I always wander over the whole earth in search of a sacred spot. **I do not, however, see any spot that is more sacred than the crematorium.** Hence, of all abodes, the crematorium pleases my heart most, shaded that it generally is by branches of the banian and adorned with torn garlands of flowers. O thou of sweet smiles, the multitudes of ghostly beings that are my companions love to reside in such spots. I do not like, O goddess, to reside anywhere without those ghostly creatures being by my side. Hence, the crematorium is a sacred abode to me. Indeed, O auspicious lady, it seems to me to be the very heaven. Highly sacred and possessed of great merit, the crematorium is much applauded by persons desirous of having holy abodes.'